# Count rows with same colum value for certain date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table layout (for columns):

ID renterID BookID dateOfRental

And I was asked to make a report page where I could see how many books each renterID has rented on a certain date. Now I am not even sure this is possible, but I thought I'd ask you guys for at least a direction or similar snippet from which I can learn?

Comment: Also, the dateOfRental column is a DATE one, not a DATETIME one

Comment: Search for `SQL`, `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Darko - note that you can edit your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT
   renterID
 , COUNT(DISTINCT BookID)
FROM
   your_table
WHERE
     dateOfRental = 'the_date'
-- or if you want a date period:  dateOfRental BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
GROUP BY
   renterID
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want this for a particular date:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) BookCount, 
   renterId, 
   dateOfRental 
FROM
   someTable
WHERE
   dateOfRental = [a certain date]
GROUP BY 
   renterId
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by simple group by :

```
SELECT renterID , dateOfRental , COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY renterID , dateOfRental
```